# Why is += (addition assignment, plus equal) so slow in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

In certain versions of node, `a += b` is significantly slower than `a = a + b`, but similar in the browser and later versions. What causes them to run so differently?

- `node v6.10.0 (V8 5.1.281.93)`, 75% slower, or reverse is 4x faster
- `node v8.0.0  (V8 5.8.283.41)`, 86% slower, or reverse is 7x faster
- `node v8.2.1  (V8 5.8.283.41)`, 86% slower, or reverse is 7x faster
- `node v8.3.0  (V8 6.0.286.52)`, similar
- `node v8.7.0  (v8 6.1.534.42)`, similar
- `node v8.9.2  (V8 6.1.534.48)`, similar
- `chrome 62.0.3202.94 (V8 6.1.534.42)`, similar
- `safari 11.0.1`, similar

Edit: found that it's related to node's v8 engine update from 5 to 6.

Snippet:

```
const iter = 10 * 1000 * 1000

function one() {
  let i = 0
  let sum = 0
  while (i < iter) {
    sum += i
    i++
  }
}

function two() {
  let i = 0
  let sum = 0
  while (i < iter) {
    sum = sum + i
    i++
  }
}

let time
const tries = 10

time = Date.now()
for (let i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
  one()
}
console.log('one: ' + String(Date.now() - time))

time = Date.now()
for (let i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
  two()
}
console.log('two: ' + String(Date.now() - time))
```

Comment: Did you try switching the order of the tests `two` and `one`? _Homemade_ tests aren't always reliable.

Comment: what would that change? @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: I've tried switching the order, "just because", but get the same result

Comment: Looks like the bug is fixed, at least as of node v8.9.2 (V8 6.1.534.48)

Comment: It's not "the bug" by definition. The standard does not guarantee they are implemented identically and have similar performance characteristics. Your benchmarks are unreliable: the function calls are invariant to the loop.

Comment: Trying to find an answer to this lead me to the discovery that Github does not allow me to search for `"+="`, `"=="`, or `"+"` in a project.  Apparently in any project, that is.

Comment: I've created a [**JSPerf test**](https://jsperf.com/assignment-plus-equal-vs-equal-plus/1). It is confirmed: `a += b;` is slower than `a = a + b;`. But not by a big margin though.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you can also copy paste this snippet into dev tools, get a result depending on your browser's JS interpreter

Comment: @Billiam I've done that initially (in node, with reversing and everything) but as I said _not reliable_.

Comment: Sorry I read wrong, fixed the edit :)

Comment: https://jsperf.com/assignment-plus-equal-vs-equal-plus/4 --- for me "nothing" is marginally (~2-10%) faster than either of those cases. Does it look trustworthy?

Answer (score 4):

This is not an issue in Node, but with the V8 engine (which Node happens to use). There's a list of "bailout reasons" on the github page (github.com/vhf/v8-bailout-reasons), which are language constructs that kill optimization. "Unsupported let compound assignment", that is, compound assignment with let-bound variables, is one of them. If you profile the code in Chromium's dev tools, you should be able to see "Not optimized: Unsupported let compound assignment": https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBlp3.png

Comment: Some good news about v8 optimization (or fresh hope for better future):

“All these optimization killers you learned throughout the years?
Forget It 
You won't need them. Use whatever you want.
Something still slow? File a bug! We'll fix it.” @bmeurer #jskongress

Source:
https://twitter.com/slsoftworks/status/930041069529690112
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=283&v=cvybnv79Sek